# Is the memoryview object used correctly in this snippet?

Tags: python, memory-efficient, memoryview

I need to find all the palindromes that occur in a certain text. I will extract the data from an external file. I need to take care of memory efficient handling of the data, therefore I use a memoryview object. However, I need to perform some string operations on the memoryview object so I used the tobytes() method. Is this the correct way to handle these objects without copying the data?

```
from collections import Counter

palindrome = []
# read file as binary data
with open('some_text.txt', 'rb') as fr:

    # create memoryview object
    data = memoryview(fr.read())

    # applying the tobytes() method
    text = data.tobytes()

    # split the sentences to words
    for word in text.split():
        # append to palindrome list if true
        if is_palindome(word):
            palindrome.append(word)

    # return a Counter object with the palindromes and the number of occurences
    palindrome = Counter(palindrome)
    print(palindrome)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use `bytes` from `fr.read()`

```
    with open('some_text.txt', 'rb') as f:
        b = f.read()
        print(b.__class__, id(b), len(b))
        data = memoryview(b)
        text = data.tobytes()
        print(text.__class__, id(text), len(text))
```

Possible output:

```
<class 'bytes'> 47642448 173227
<class 'bytes'> 47815728 173227
```

For CPython `id()` returns the [addres](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#id) of the object in memory. So `data.tobytes()` returns a copy in this case.

Consider to use the text mode

`with open('some_text.txt', 'r') as f:`